# Bash for loop doesn't finish looping

Tags: bash

I want to get a list of subdirs, cd into each and run a command, here's what I'm trying:

```
#!/bin/bash
for D in installedPlugins/*; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
        cd "${D}" && echo "${D}" && cd ..
    fi
done
```

It does this for the first subdir but does not continue for some reason.

Comment: `find installedPlugins/ -type d` will give all sub directories that you can use to do wahtever

Comment: You can use `cd -` to return to the previous directory

Comment: On another note, you could bypass the `[ -d "$D" ]` check, if you just use `for D in installedPlugins/*/; do`. ... (Note extra `/` after `*`.) This will also reduce the loop iterations (normal files will not be part of the glob expansion; only directories.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script traverses 2 directories into `${D}` but only one directory out (`cd ..`). For example:

```
cd "installedPlugins/SomeDir" && echo "installedPlugins/SomeDir" && cd ..
```

...and *voilà!* The currect directory for your script is now "installedPlugins/".

You probably meant to use `cd ../..` or `cd -` instead. As already noted in the commands, it is better to use `find` to iterate over the directories, e.g.:

```
find installedPlugins/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec echo "{}" \;
```

Comment: However, [do not use a `for` loop to iterate over the output of `find`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: There is really no benefit to using `find` when a glob will do just as well.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, removed the erronous example

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way with `pushd` and `popd`. They're sort of noisy, so I'm sending their output to `/dev/null`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for D in installedPlugins/*; do
    test -d "$D" && {
        pushd "$D" > /dev/null
        pwd
        popd > /dev/null
    }
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the second iteration's `cd` fails because the first iteration changed your working directory :

- 1st iteration, `$D` is installedPlugins/something. You `cd` into ./installedPlugins/something/, then cd back to ./installedPlugins
- 2nd iteration, `$D` is installedPlugins/somethingElse. you `cd` into ./installedPlugins/somethingElse, but that fails because you already are into installedPlugins.

You could use a simple `find` to solve your problem :

```
find ./installedPlugins/ -type d
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your in a deeper directory once you `cd`:

```
for D in installedPlugins/*; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
        cd "${D}" && echo "${D}" && cd ../.. # notice change here
    fi
done
```

On the first `cd` you've to depth 2, not 1, relative to your point. So you need to go back 2 levels.

**Note:** You should be using `find` for this task.

Comment: There's nothing in the question that suggests `find` would be an improvement.